# Is there any algebraic structure on Dyck words of length $2n$ or full binary trees of $n+1$ leaves?

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-languages, trees, catalan-numbers, combinatorics-on-words

Just out of curiosity, I wonder if there are researches about **algebraic structures on** [Dyck words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) **of length $2n$ or (equivalently)** [full binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#full) **of $n+1$ leaves** (with fixed $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$).

As a matter of fact, that two sets have the same number of elements: the $n^{th}$ Catalan number $C_n$.

I've googled but got no result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870898917595

Comment: @Phicar: There is the fixed length $n$, whereas the paper mostly talks about planar binary trees of any number of leaves, which is equivalent to the Dyck language. There are already some algebraic researches about the Dyck language as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a huge literature on this topic. See Chapter 11, Words and trees, in [2] and Lemma 9.3.1 in
[4] for your specific question. See the notes of Chapter 9 in [3] for (many) relevant references. Reference [3] doesn't address your question but is still a good reference on algebra over words. For an algebraic theory of context-free languages, see [2] and Chapter 2 in [1]

[1] Berstel, Jean. [Transductions and context-free languages](http://www.infop7.org/file/659/LivreTransductions14dec2009.pdf). Leitfäden der Angewandten Mathematik und Mechanik [Guides to Applied Mathematics and Mechanics], 38. B. G. Teubner, Stuttgart, 1979. 278 pp. ISBN: 3-519-02340-7

[1] Berstel, J.; Boasson, L. [Towards an algebraic theory of context-free languages](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Mps/Travaux/A/1963-7ChomskyAlgebraic.pdf), Fund. Inform. 25 (1996), no. 3-4, 217--239

[2] Lothaire, M. Combinatorics on words. With a foreword by Roger Lyndon and a preface by Dominique Perrin. Corrected reprint of the 1983 original, with a new preface by Perrin. Cambridge Mathematical Library. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1997. xviii+238 pp. ISBN: 0-521-59924-5

[3] Lothaire, M. Algebraic combinatorics on words. A collective work by Jean Berstel, Dominique Perrin, Patrice Seebold, Julien Cassaigne, Aldo De Luca, Steffano Varricchio, Alain Lascoux, Bernard Leclerc, Jean-Yves Thibon, Veronique Bruyere, Christiane Frougny, Filippo Mignosi, Antonio Restivo, Christophe Reutenauer, Dominique Foata, Guo-Niu Han, Jacques Desarmenien, Volker Diekert, Tero Harju, Juhani Karhumaki and Wojciech Plandowski. With a preface by Berstel and Perrin. Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, 90. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2002. xiv+504 pp. ISBN: 0-521-81220-8 MR1905123

[4] Lothaire, M. [Applied combinatorics on words](http://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~duchamp/Books&more/Lothaire/(Encyclopedia_of_Mathematics_and_its_Applications_)M._Lothaire-Applied_Combinatorics_On_Words-Cambridge_University_Press(2005).pdf). A collective work by Jean Berstel, Dominique Perrin, Maxime Crochemore, Eric Laporte, Mehryar Mohri, Nadia Pisanti, Marie-France Sagot, Gesine Reinert, Sophie Schbath, Michael Waterman, Philippe Jacquet, Wojciech Szpankowski, Dominique Poulalhon, Gilles Schaeffer, Roman Kolpakov, Gregory Koucherov, Jean-Paul Allouche and Valérie Berthé. With a preface by Berstel and Perrin. Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, 105. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2005. xvi+610 pp. ISBN: 978-0-521-84802-2; 0-521-84802-4